# Converting 10.10 desktop iso to alternate iso

Tags: 10.10

Is there any utility available to convert ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso to alternate cd image file?

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: You might as well just download the second iso...

Answer (score 5):

I do not know what you mean by "convert". You may want to use zsync to download alternative cd using desctop cd as a base:

zsync -i maverick-desktop-i386.iso http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/maverick-alternate-i386.iso.zsync

In that case zsync will download only those parts of alternate cd that are different from desktop one.

Comment: Almost everything between those 2 CDs is different, so just downloading the alternate .iso is going to be faster and cause less network traffic...

Answer (score 5):

In short, no.
The alternate CD has the compressed .deb packages & the installer from Debian, whereas the desktop CD has a squashfs image of an unpacked filesystem, which is copied over. The compression used is different, so rsync or zsync won't work well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that is possible since they provide different installers, also that would require to recreate the install packages from the livecd image, which would be too complex.